# vimdiff in Git for Windows gives E810 and E97

Tags: windows-7, bash, vim, git

I'm using Git for Windows (git version 2.5.3.windows.1) and I've set up vimdiff as my mergetool. Running `git mergetool` from git bash results in the following error:

```
E810: Cannot read or write temp files
E97: Cannot create diffs
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Now, I know what you're thinking, this is a duplicate of [cant-run-vimdiff-7-4-on-windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/697847/cant-run-vimdiff-7-4-on-windows-7), but I tried the solution and it doesn't work (or I'm missing something). Plus, I didn't install vim, it came with Git for Windows, and I think it may be different (not 100% sure).

Here is my `~/.vimrc` file (at the bottom you'll see I've added the `MyDiff()` and `set diffexpr=MyDiff()`, maybe I've done it wrong?) (Also, for what it's worth, the "top part" of this is not from the "sample" vimrc from Git for Windows, but the one from Cygwin, but I doubt this matters.):

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2014 Nov 05
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file (restore to previous version)
  set undofile      " keep an undo file (undo changes after closing)
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
  " position when opening a file.
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif

if has('langmap') && exists('+langnoremap')
  " Prevent that the langmap option applies to characters that result from a
  " mapping.  If unset (default), this may break plugins (but it's backward
  " compatible).
  set langnoremap
endif

" Set tab width stuff
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 noexpandtab shiftwidth=4

" Assign diff tool to MyDiff() method
set diffexpr=MyDiff()

" Used for diff
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      if empty(&shellxquote)
        let l:shxq_sav = ''
        set shellxquote&
      endif
      let cmd = '"' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3
  if exists('l:shxq_sav')
    let &shellxquote=l:shxq_sav
  endif
endfunction
```

To be thorough, `:version` gives this:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Sep 16 2015 08:44:57)
Included patches: 1-872
Compiled by <alexpux@gmail.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cmdline_compl   +diff            +find_in_path    +keymap          +modify_fname    +mouse_xterm     +profile         -sniff           +termresponse    +vreplace        -xterm_save
+arabic          +cmdline_hist    +digraphs        +float           +langmap         +mouse           +multi_byte      +python/dyn      +startuptime     +textobjects     +wildignore      -xpm
+autocmd         +cmdline_info    -dnd             +folding         +libcall         -mouseshape      +multi_lang      +python3/dyn     +statusline      +title           +wildmenu
-balloon_eval    +comments        -ebcdic          -footer          +linebreak       +mouse_dec       -mzscheme        +quickfix        -sun_workshop    -toolbar         +windows
-browse          +conceal         +emacs_tags      +fork()          +lispindent      -mouse_gpm       +netbeans_intg   +reltime         +syntax          +user_commands   +writebackup
++builtin_terms  +cryptv          +eval            +gettext         +listcmds        -mouse_jsbterm   +path_extra      +rightleft       +tag_binary      +vertsplit       -X11
+byte_offset     +cscope          +ex_extra        -hangul_input    +localmap        +mouse_netterm   +perl/dyn        +ruby/dyn        +tag_old_static  +virtualedit     -xfontset
+cindent         +cursorbind      +extra_search    +iconv           -lua             +mouse_sgr       +persistent_undo +scrollbind      -tag_any_white   +visual          -xim
-clientserver    +cursorshape     +farsi           +insert_expand   +menu            -mouse_sysmouse  +postscript      +signs           -tcl             +visualextra     -xsmp
+clipboard       +dialog_con      +file_in_path    +jumplist        +mksession       +mouse_urxvt     +printer         +smartindent     +terminfo        +viminfo         -xterm_clipboard
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/usr/include/ncursesw  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -pipe -fstack-protector -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -o vim.exe        -lm    -lncursesw -liconv -lintl   -pipe -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the purpose of the `MyDiff()`, I thought it was for using vim on Windows *in general*, it is for using vim on Windows in cmd specifically -- but I am using it through git bash. The solution was to remove all that and as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32553645/1858327) run this:

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 git mergetool
```

Or I could set `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` in my `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

```
# Set MSYS to not convert paths
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```